# Way to generically iterate through entities in XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a generic way, in T-SQL, to iterate through an xml variable and get *the xml* for each entity in turn?

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'<Entities>
<Entity key="4" attrib1="abc" attrib2="def" />
<Entity key="18" attrib1="ghi" attrib2="jkl" />
<Entity key="938" attrib1="mno" />
</Entities>'
```

For example, in the above XML, there are three instances of Entity. I want the XML for each one in turn. I can do this in a hard-coded way, e.g.

```
SELECT @entityxml = @xml.query('/Entities/Entity[1]')
```

which will return

```
    <Entity key="4" attrib1="abc" attrib2="def" />
```

I can then change it to a [2] to get the next one, and so forth.

But, according to both BOL and experimentation, the parameter to @xml.query must be a string literal. In other words, a variable can't be used as the parameter, building it with [1], [2], etc., and getting however many entities there are. It appears we have hard-code the queries, which makes for some ugly code.

I know other methods can be used to get the data in the xml into a table, and then iterate through the rows in the table.  I'm specifically asking about getting the XML itself, i.e. getting the equivalent of the above @xml.query, but being able to do so without having to hard-code the array value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [position()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191225.aspx) to select elements based on index:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'<Entities>
<Entity key="4" attrib1="abc" attrib2="def" />
<Entity key="18" attrib1="ghi" attrib2="jkl" />
<Entity key="938" attrib1="mno" />
</Entities>'

declare @i int;
set @i = 2;

select @xml.query('Entities/Entity[position()=sql:variable("@i")]');
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. The next question is: how/where did you learn that? :)  I'd love to learn more about XML in SQL, but stuff like that isn't covered in the BOL (at least that I can find), and I haven't found a good place Googling, either. Thanks again!

Comment: Check out the msdn link. You'll find info on all available xquery functions there. This is also a good site:  http://milambda.blogspot.com/2008/03/sql-server-xqueryxpath-retrieval.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'<Entities>
<Entity key="4" attrib1="abc" attrib2="def" />
<Entity key="18" attrib1="ghi" attrib2="jkl" />
<Entity key="938" attrib1="mno" />
</Entities>';

SELECT @xml.query('
for $i in //Entity
return
<Entity>
    { $i/@key }
    { $i/@attrib1 }
    { $i/@attrib2 }
</Entity>
');
```